# Parsing error; I have tried and can't figure out what's wrong?

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

THIS CODE IS DRIVING ME BONKERS!! I've spent a week now trying to figure out what is wrong. 
In fact, my instructor also could not find an issue within the code-so that's quite frustrating...especially because it won't compile due to a supposed parsing issue.
Any help would be more than amazing and very much appreciated!! (and if it's not too much of a bother, could you please explain to me why you make the adjustments that you do?)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChooseYourOwnAdventure
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    { 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Wh, Kt, yn, WH2, ny;

        System.out.println("WELCOME TO MITCHELL'S TINY ADVENTURE!");

        System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go \"upstairs\" or into the \"kitchen\"?");
        Wh = keyboard.next();
        {
            if (Wh.equals("kitchen"))
            {
                System.out.println( "There is a long counter top with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the \"refrigerator\" or look in a \"cabinet\".");
                Kt = keyboard.next();
            }
            if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals ("refrigerator")))
            {
                 System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would  you like to eat some of the food? (\"yes\" or \"no\") ");
                yn = keyboard.next();
            }
            if (Kt.equals (("refrigerator") && yn.equals("no")))
            {
                System.out.println("You die of starvation...eventually.");
            }
            if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals ("cabinet")))
            {   
                System.out.println("Everything is rodent infested. Roaches everywhere! I think we even saw a rat!");
            }
            if (Wh.equals("upstairs"))
            {
            System.out.println("Upstairs you see a hallway. At the end of the hallway is the master \"bedroom\". There is also a \"bathroom\" off the hallway. Where would you like to go?");
                    WH2 = keyboard.next();
            }
            if (WH2.equals("bedroom"))
            {
                System.out.println("You are in a plush bedroom, with expensive-looking hardwood furniture. The bed is unmade. In the back of the room, the closet door is ajar. Would you like to open the door? (\"yes\" or \"no\")");
                ny = keyboard.next();
            }
            if ((WH2.equals("bedroom") && (ny.equals ("No"))))
            {
                System.out.println("Well then I guess you'll never know what was in there. Thanks for playing, I'm tired of making nested if statements.");
            }
            if (WH2.equals("bathroom"))
            {
                System.out.println("It stinks in there! We are going back to the hallway!");
            }

        System.out.println("Thanks for playing...");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a stack trace or comment the line that gives the compilation issue?

Comment: What is the exact message you're getting?

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals("refrigerator")))
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (Wh.equals("kitchen") && Kt.equals("refrigerator"))
```

Same thing for your other `if` statements.

Also the variable `WH2` is never initialized which will cause an error when you call `equals()` on it.

Comment: +1 to you for having eagle-eyes.  Or using an IDE to tell you where the parenthesis didn't match.

Comment: I must confess I cheated and used an IDE to catch the errors :)

Comment: @Petter This is not cheating, this is taking advantage of useful tools! :D

Answer (score 1):

You have double brackets - (Wh.equals((, Kt.equals (( and Wh.equals(( - with the closing )) on each part - it should only be 1 bracket in each case.

Comment: Thanks for reading the other answers for us... or are you just a really slow typer?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Lol - oh yes - a late starter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Initalize the strings and make the changed as below. Otherwise you will get error Kt, yn, WH2 and ny as not initailized.

```
public class ChooseYourOwnAdventure
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{ 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Wh="", Kt="", yn="", WH2="", ny="";

    System.out.println("WELCOME TO MITCHELL'S TINY ADVENTURE!");

    System.out.println("You are in a creepy house! Would you like to go \"upstairs\" or into the \"kitchen\"?");
    Wh = keyboard.next();
    {
        if (Wh.equals("kitchen"))
        {
            System.out.println( "There is a long counter top with dirty dishes everywhere. Off to one side there is, as you'd expect, a refrigerator. You may open the \"refrigerator\" or look in a \"cabinet\".");
            Kt = keyboard.next();
        }
        if (Wh.equals("kitchen") && Kt.equals ("refrigerator"))
        {
             System.out.println("Inside the refrigerator you see food and stuff. It looks pretty nasty. Would  you like to eat some of the food? (\"yes\" or \"no\") ");
            yn = keyboard.next();
        }
        if (Kt.equals ("refrigerator") && yn.equals("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("You die of starvation...eventually.");
        }
        if (Wh.equals("kitchen") && Kt.equals ("cabinet"))
        {   
            System.out.println("Everything is rodent infested. Roaches everywhere! I think we even saw a rat!");
        }
        if (Wh.equals("upstairs"))
        {
        System.out.println("Upstairs you see a hallway. At the end of the hallway is the master \"bedroom\". There is also a \"bathroom\" off the hallway. Where would you like to go?");
                WH2 = keyboard.next();
        }
        if (WH2.equals("bedroom"))
        {
            System.out.println("You are in a plush bedroom, with expensive-looking hardwood furniture. The bed is unmade. In the back of the room, the closet door is ajar. Would you like to open the door? (\"yes\" or \"no\")");
            ny = keyboard.next();
        }
        if ((WH2.equals("bedroom") && (ny.equals ("No"))))
        {
            System.out.println("Well then I guess you'll never know what was in there. Thanks for playing, I'm tired of making nested if statements.");
        }
        if (WH2.equals("bathroom"))
        {
            System.out.println("It stinks in there! We are going back to the hallway!");
        }

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing...");

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals("refrigerator")))
```

It should be

```
if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals("refrigerator")))
```

Same error for below two ifs

```
if (Kt.equals(("refrigerator") && yn.equals("no")))

if (Wh.equals(("kitchen") && Kt.equals("cabinet")))
```